# Understand price optimization using PuLP and formulate problem

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, pulp, integer-programming

I am trying to write a small price optimization engine that optimizes revenues given a list of articles.

I have a list of articles and for each of them, I have its price elasticity of demand. My constraints are currently not defined, however, there will be definitely something putting a roof to the maximum price and the minimum price.

Currently, I am stuck in finding a way in which I could write down to the model the relationship of price and price elasticity, more precisely the model should have a constraint that understands that if an item is very elastic changing its price will affect a lot of quantity sold.

Moreover, I am actually not sure which kind of data I really need as input variables. Do I need something like a list of prices and quantity sold at different price points?

Comment: please your formula optimization

Comment: I am actually having problems exactly to define the formula I want to optimize. Since I partially know which data I need to achieve this. Thanks for your comment :-)

Comment: @sanna, have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid elasticities introduce nonlinearities in the model:

```
 log(Q) = C + Elasticity * log(P)
```

where C is a constant. Or stated differently:

```
  Q =  K * P^Elasticity
```

where `K = Exp(C)` is again a constant.

These types of nonlinearities are typical in many economic models. They are often solved with non-linear solvers. PuLP is for linear models only, so if you want to use that you may want to use a linear approximation (i.e. a linear demand function). You probably should discuss this with your teacher or supervisor.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, alternatively, I might consider also using SciPy non-linear solvers: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html would it be better?

Comment: These are not very sophisticated solvers, and the way to specify models is only suitable for small toy problems. I tend to stay away from them. I have never seen any serious economic model using these solvers.